# Best place to start learning how to use Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Where can an absolute noob learn how to develop using Intel XDK. Ive searched for tutorials all around but I can't find a thorough enough tutorial to help guide me through the process or developing hybrid apps.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,Its quite hard to find good tutorials on Intel XDK, Though this guy is awesome,and has some great stuff in his website.You can even find video tutorials(Though you have to pay for that).
http://qnimate.com/post-series/intel-xdk-complete-training/

Answer (score 4):

Intel has a series of video tutorials starting at https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/intel-xdk-app-starter-tutorials-lesson-1-getting-started

Comment: And the main doc pages are located here: http://www.intel.com/software/xdkdocs

Comment: I think the videos have been removed :(